# Stored procedure commit after DELETE and UPDATE run successfully

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[DeleteQualityAssemblyProduction]
@id int,
@Quantity int,
@idPartShip int,
@FK_idNextProcess int
AS
DELETE FROM [dbo].DailyQualityAssemblyProduction
  WHERE id=@id
if @FK_idNextProcess=11

Begin
UPDATE [dbo].[ProjectShipping]
SET 
  QualityAssemblyQty = QualityAssemblyQty- @Quantity

WHERE id=@idPartShip
End
```

I want when both DELETE and UPDATE run successfully COMMIT the changes otherwise ROLLBACK .
I was wondering if adding COMMIT in the end of stored procedure do the job or I need other method

Comment: Use a transaction in your procedure. Also add a TRY/CATCH.

Comment: thank you very much can you please write it in answer section  so I can make it as an answer for my question, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could tackle this. This is adding a transaction which you will need to handle multiple DML statements in one autonomous block. Then added a try/catch so that if either statement fails the transaction will deal with both statements as one unit of work.

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[DeleteQualityAssemblyProduction]
(
    @id int,
    @Quantity int,
    @idPartShip int,
    @FK_idNextProcess int
) AS

    set nocount on;
    begin transaction

    begin try

        DELETE FROM [dbo].DailyQualityAssemblyProduction
        WHERE id = @id

        if @FK_idNextProcess = 11
        begin
            UPDATE [dbo].[ProjectShipping]
            SET QualityAssemblyQty = QualityAssemblyQty - @Quantity
            WHERE id = @idPartShip
        end

        commit transaction
    end try

    begin catch
        rollback transaction

        declare @error int
            , @message varchar(4000);

        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER()
            , @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()

        raiserror ('DeleteQualityAssemblyProduction: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch
```